# NSClassFromString performance

Tags: ios, objective-c

Will there be any performance benefits in using NSClassFromString?
Especially when comparing with the standard way of importing the class from header and initializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. If anything, `NSClassFromString` is slower than the normal way of using a class!

Comment: Can you specify what makes it slower than a normal way of class usage?

Comment: @Vivek - just make a benchmark ;) I just know the internals ob ObjC pretty well, and `NSClassFromString` has to be slower than the normal way, because it just does so much more work. You can look at the disassembly to see this.

Comment: @Vivek for one thing, when you normally use a class the name is resolved at load-time; when you use `NSClassFromString`, the class is resolved at runtime. Furhtermore, the ObjC-developers were pretty smart: If `NSClassFromString` were faster then the compiler would generate `NSClassFromString` calls whenever you use a class, instead of doing what it does now.

Comment: So now I think, we should use this only if a verification is required, to perform a check on the availability of the class. And if we are sure about the availability of the class then we should import it and use in the normal way. There will be zero performance benefit for NSClassFromString over normal way of usage.

Comment: @Vivek I think it's hard to pull that method off in practice (although not totally impossible). Say you use the pattern `if(NSClassFromString(@"MyClass")){[MyClass foo];}` and `MyClass` is not available, that code snippet will not even compile (you'll get an error during static link time, not load time => you cannot run this program). On the other hand, if the class is available, the `if(NSClassFromString(@"MyClass"))` part is pointless. So, the snippet `if(NSClassFromString(@"MyClass")){[MyClass foo];}` either fails at compile-time, or the condition in the `if` is a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can think that using `NSStringFromClass()` is an alternative to importing the class declaration and letting the compiler do the work.

Given the compiler won't have seen the declaration, the object will be next to useless and you would be forced to convert strings into selectors in order to be able to call them.

It certainly won't be faster than importing the declaration via the header file.

Comment: I was googling on "how nsclassfromstring works". But cant find anything useful :(

Comment: @Vivek Using it at all is not an alternative to importing the header and letting the compiler do the work.  They are like chalk and cheese.

Answer (score 0):

NSClassFromString is a runtime commande, which mean it will perform, at runtime, a fetch in a "database" to find a loaded class matching the given name.
Firstly, it is not recommended to use it when you could use the basis #import pattern (which will perform the fetch at compile time, so the final user won't notice it). it will provide less code safety, which could lead to "really hard to debug" issues.
It might comes a time when you need it, for example when creating a Class at runtime, or when trying to parse a json object or dictionaries to concrete class.